# Filter is not display after custome product_listing.xml

Tags: uicomponent, magento-2.1.3, product-grid, uielement

I am trying to add new column in magento 2.1.3 **admin -> Catalog -> Product grid**

I used following code to display sale column in product grid

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
            <column name="sale">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sale</item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Deactive</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

I have put this code in **view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

**Issue** is when i used this product_listing.xml file product grid filter  not displayed and when i click on filter icon filter is display on bottom of grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right i am getting the same issue and i have resolved it by **below code :**

Here you are missing **listingToolbar** so you need to add toolbar at top of the columns section.

`<listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>`

**Try below code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>
        <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
            <column name="sale">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sale</item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Deactive</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```